# Convert a polynomial represented as a list of coefficients to a string

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, polynomials

I know this is a newbish question. I am trying to create a function 'displayPoly' to display a polynomial in scheme. For example a list given as 
'(2 0 1 5.1 8) should display 2x^4 + x^2 + 5.1x + 8.

I have defined "degree" as the following:

```
 (define degree
 (lambda(list)
  (if (null? list) 
      (- 1)
  (+ 1  (degree (cdr list))))))
```

Please note I am strictly limited to basic scheme functions 
•define, lambda, if, cond, cons,car, cdr, list , member, list-ref
•predicates :  null?  list?  equal? string?  number?  member?
•arithmetic operators , relational operators,  logical operators
•sort, map, filter, foldr, foldl, length, reverse, append, last , let, let*, letrec, print, begin, newline, display, expt, string-append, reduce, range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write some helper functions.

1. Write a function that given a polynomial returns a list of the degrees.

   Input: '(2 0 1 5.1 8)
   Output: (4 3 2 1   0)
2. Write a function `mono` that given a coefficient and a degree outputs a monomial as a string.

   Input:  2 4
   Output: "2x^4"
3. Use `(map mono '(2 0 1 5.1 8) (4 3 2 1   0))` to produce a list of the monomials.
4. Use `add-between` (or write one yourself) to add "+" between all your monomials.
5. Use `(apply string-append your-list-of-monomials)` to get you final string.

Note: It's possible to produce prettier output, but this is a good start.

Comment: The suggestion would pose a problem for negative coefficients. eg. `(-1 2 -5)` should make `-x^2 + 2x - 5`.

Comment: Or `(-1)x^2 + 2x + (-5)` which is not perfect, but at least correct.

Comment: @skywester the way the negatives were displayed wasnt a problem. as long as the "+" showed in between. Anyhow I got it to work using recursion, and display. The only problem I got was it would show the 0. i.e (5 0 3 -2 1) = 5x^4 + 0x^3 + 3x^2 + -2x + 1. I tried to map mono, and filter, but had no luck. Guess this will have to do. Thank you :)

Comment: @MohammadArshad If the answer helped, consider accepting the answer by clicking the green check mark.